# Error: Dialog[BotBuilder:/menu] not found

Tags: jquery, node.js, botframework

Please guide me. What is wrong.  I have menu option at place it was using for other dialog and work well. but in below code its not working.

```
bot.dialog('/My Subscriptions', [
    function (session, args) {
        session.send('My Subscriptions Menu');
        session.userData.profile.CurrntSubscriptionsView = true;
        displaytheSubscriptions(session);
    },
]);

function displaytheSubscriptions(session)
{
    var subscribedArray = '';
    var indexVal = 1;
    for(var i in selectedSubArray) {
        //console.log (i, selectedSubArray[i]);
        subscribedArray += indexVal+'. '+selectedSubArray[i]+'\n';
        indexVal++;
    }
    if (subscribedArray.length > 0) {
        builder.Prompts.text(session, "Subscriptions List\n\n"+subscribedArray);
    } else {
        session.send(wrongMsg);
    }
    session.send("flag is "+session.userData.profile.CurrntSubscriptionsView);
    if(session.userData.profile.CurrntSubscriptionsView === true) { 
        session.send('You will be redirecting you to previous menu.');
        session.replaceDialog('/menu');
    } else { 
        builder.Prompts.text(session, "Select your Unsubscriptions [ Multiple selectation seperate by comma (,) ]?");
    }
}

bot.dialog('/Unsubscribe', [
    function (session, args) {
        session.send('Unsubscribe Menu');
        session.userData.profile.CurrntSubscriptionsView = false;
        displaytheSubscriptions(session);

    },
    function(session, results) { 
        session.send(results.response);
        if(results.response.entity != '') { 
            session.send("You entered '%s'", results.response);
            session.userData.profile.CurrntSubscribeList = results.response;
            session.beginDialog('/Confrim Unsubscribe');
        }
    }
]);
```

When I select the Unsubscribe menu it works well but when I select the My Subscriptions menu option from the choice. it return me the error in bot & skype

Skype Show me the message "**Oops. Something went wrong and we need to start over.**"

and Bot show me error.

```
restify listening to http://[::]:3978
Error: Dialog[BotBuilder:/menu] not found.
    at Session.replaceDialog (node_modules/botbuilder/lib/Session.js:188:19)
    at displaytheSubscriptions (start.js:1701:17)
    at Array.<anonymous> (start.js:1680:9)
    at SimpleDialog.waterfallAction [as fn] (node_modules/botbuilder/lib/dialogs/DialogAction.js:131:25)
    at SimpleDialog.begin (node_modules/botbuilder/lib/dialogs/SimpleDialog.js:15:14)
    at Session.beginDialog (node_modules/botbuilder/lib/Session.js:180:16)
    at Array.<anonymous> (start.js:324:25)
    at SimpleDialog.waterfallAction [as fn] (node_modules/botbuilder/lib/dialogs/DialogAction.js:117:32)
    at SimpleDialog.dialogResumed (node_modules/botbuilder/lib/dialogs/SimpleDialog.js:21:14)
    at Session.endDialogWithResult (node_modules/botbuilder/lib/Session.js:279:28)
```

Comment: Well if that is your complete code, then I see the problem., in `displaytheSubscriptions(session)` your code calls the function `session.replaceDialog("/menu");` , but nowhere in your code is there a `bot.dialog("/menu", <handler> )` endpoint to take over the current dialog.

Comment: @TonyAnziano  Its not completed code, I just mention error occur bot dialog and Yes, I have bot.dialog('/meu', [handler] );